# How to convert this eventlistener to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I refactor the below snippet to using jQuery.

```
  window.onload = function () {
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("message", doSomething, false);
        }
        else {
            if (window.attachEvent) {
                window.attachEvent("onmessage", doSomething);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is such a small bit of code and it will work with jQuery as it is now, why change? Do you want to make a plugin? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

Comment: @JayBlanchard If I included jQuery I would certainly do everything through jQuery's library, if possible.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I already have jQuery and I need to do some fancy form submittion trickery which I would rather do with jQuery.

Comment: But why @Wobbuffet? It isn't necessary and some parts of vanilla JS are much quicker, like for loops vs. the each() method.

Comment: Although I provided an answer, I do agree with this, a bit. if this is a single instance of code, by all means, jQuery probably won't help you unless you're looking for the added functionality that jQuery gives you.

Comment: Everyone keeps bringing up SUCH GOOD POINTS. I'll bow out here.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, you can simply do this:

```
$(window).on("message", doSomething);
```

This attaches an event handler for the `"message"` event to the window object.

---

FYI, there's no need to wait for `window.onload` just to attach an event handler to the `window` object as it already exists so there's no need to wait.

If you did need to wait for some other reason, you could put it inside of:

```
// wait for all document resources to load
$(window).load(function() {
    // code here
});
```

or

```
// wait for DOM to be loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
    // code here
});
```

depending upon what you needed to wait for.

Comment: do I have to do this from inside the $(document).ready() block?

Comment: @publicstatic - no you don't have to wait to install event handlers on the `window` object because it already exists and is already available for events.

Comment: While that's true (and I just learned that because now it makes so much sense.) I'd probably still throw everything into a `ready()` block, just so I don't have one sad, lonely piece of code crying outside of my primary execution block.

Comment: @Morklympious - I personally like to only put things in a `.ready()` block that actually need to be there.  Other things can execute sooner and get done sooner.  In this particular case, it is possible you could receive a message before your own document was done loading perhaps from an embedded iframe that somehow loads faster.

Comment: @jfriend00 Point made. I just suppose I haven't had a lot of experience outside of having anything execute outside of waiting for the DOM to load. Thanks for the example, too! :)

Comment: I'm using this for cross-site scripting and it doesn't seem to be working when I use jquery...not sure why though unfort.

Comment: @publicstatic - there's nothing unusual about listening for this message event just like any other events using jQuery.  I'd suggest going through the usual debugging steps.  Are there any errors in your error log?  Are you sure jQuery is loaded before you try to use it?

Comment: I make a post call to a 3rd party service, and that service then calls a javascript function on my end.  It was working w/o jquery so yes I'll debug it but not sure how since the call to my function is done remotely.

Comment: @publicstatic - not much we can do here without seeing the actual code and understanding the whole setup.

Answer (score 1):

If 'onmessage' and 'message' are events specific to the `window` object, You can wrap the window in a jQuery wrapper `$(window)`

And then you can use jQuery's event system to bind those events with `.on()`

So it'd look something like this:

```
$(window).on('message', function(){ // do something });
$(window).on('onmessage', function(){ // do something });
```

You can read more about [.on() at the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Some people will tell you to use bind, but from the docs:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.

So, depending on your jQuery version, you'll either use `on()` or `bind()` accordingly.

Hope that helps!